# Google Authentication Login in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

Client error: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?prettyPrint=false` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Legacy People API has not been used in project 536929073653 before or it (truncated...)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to [https://console.cloud.google.com/apis](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=magnetic-energy-348508) and enable Google+ api.

Google Cloud does not automatically enable the api for you when you create OAuth service.

Comment: I have enabled Google+ api  but still getting same error